# Where does ElasticSearch store persistent settings?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

When I get my ElasticSearch server settings via

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cluster/settings
```

I see persistent and transient settings.

```
{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.cluster_concurrent_rebalance": "0",
    "threadpool.index.size": "20",
    "threadpool.search.size": "30",
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disable_allocation": "false",
    "threadpool.bulk.size": "40"
  },
  "transient": {}
}
```

If I set a persistent setting, it doesn't save it to my `config/elasticsearch.yml` config file? So my question is when my server restarts, how does it know what my persistent settings are?

Don't tell me not to worry about it because I almost lost my entire cluster worth of data because it picked up all the settings in my config file after it restarted, NOT the persistent settings shown above :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Persistent settings are stored on each master-eligible node in the global cluster state file, which can be found in the Elasticsearch data directory: `data/CLUSTER_NAME/nodes/N/_state`, where `CLUSTER_NAME` is the name of the cluster and `N` is the node number (`0` if this is the only node on this machine). The file name has the following format: `global-NNN` where `NNN` is the version of the cluster state.

Besides persistent settings this file may contain other global metadata such as index templates. By default the global cluster state file is stored in the binary SMILE format. For debugging purposes, if you want to see what's actually stored in this file, you can change the format of this file to JSON by adding the following line to the `elasticsearch.yml` file:

`format: json`

Every time cluster state changes, all master-eligible nodes store the new version of the file, so during cluster restart the node that starts first and elects itself as a master will have the newest version of the cluster state. What you are describing could be possible if you updated the settings when one of your master-eligible nodes was not part of the cluster (and therefore couldn't store the latest version with your settings) and after the restart this node became the cluster master and propagated its obsolete settings to all other nodes.

Comment: FWIW, your data directory is probably `/var/lib/elasticsearch` (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-dir-layout.html for specifics)