# Elasticsearch indices.breaker.fielddata.limit settings

Tags: elasticsearch

I can set the breaker.fielddata limit with CURL, but the setup from config is not respected:

ES version: 1.6.0

In my node config

> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

```
indices.breaker.fielddata.limit: 60%
#indices.breaker.fielddata.limit: 60% # this should work, but is not
#indices.fielddata.breaker.limit: 60% # this is deprecated
indices.breaker.total.limit: 70%

indices.breaker.request.limit: 50%
indices.fielddata.cache.size:  60%
```

The fielddata limit is set to 60% (4.7g of 8g heap) in the config, but:

> curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes/stats?pretty' |less
>
> ```
> "breakers" : {
>     "request" : {
>       "limit_size_in_bytes" : 4277534720,
>       "limit_size" : "3.9gb",
>       "estimated_size_in_bytes" : 0,
>       "estimated_size" : "0b",
>       "overhead" : 1.0,
>       "tripped" : 0
>     },
>     "fielddata" : {
>       "limit_size_in_bytes" : 3422027776,
>       "limit_size" : "3.1gb",
>       "estimated_size_in_bytes" : 0,
>       "estimated_size" : "0b",
>       "overhead" : 1.0,
>       "tripped" : 0
>     },
>     "parent" : {
>       "limit_size_in_bytes" : 5988548608,
>       "limit_size" : "5.5gb",
>       "estimated_size_in_bytes" : 55438576,
>       "estimated_size" : "52.8mb",
>       "overhead" : 1.0,
>       "tripped" : 0
>     }
>   }
> ```

As You see, the size of 
*indices.breaker.request.limi*t did change form 40% to 50%
while
*indices.breaker.fielddata.limi*t is still 40% (3,1g)

With a curl:

> curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings' -d '{
>   "persistent" : { "indices.breaker.fielddata.limit" : "60%" } }'

I can change the
*indices.breaker.fielddata.limit* to 60%

**Why the line form the config is not respected?**

```
indices.breaker.fielddata.limit: 60%
```

Comment: may seem like a dumb question but did you restart the node instance after changes to the config file ?

Comment: :) sure I did
Though not a whole cluster at once, but yes.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this is a known issue specified here  [issue:1](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/7704),[issue:2](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/3670).
In essence once you have dynamically updated the the breaker setting and set it as persistent there is no ideal way to reset to the defaults specified in config file.
The persistent settings are themselves are stored in the [global cluster state file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21804987/where-does-elasticsearch-store-persistent-settings) and these settings override the setting in the config file ([issue:3](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/3671))

Comment: any idea where `issue:3` was supposed to link?

Comment: @JacobKrall thanks for pointing it out i have updated the link